# "What do they do with the rest of the Matzah?"

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I don't know how many times I've been sitting and enjoying some matzah ball soup, with both Jews and non-Jews, and someone asks:

"...so what do they do with the rest of the matzah?"

I've always wondered about this myself.

I know they somehow use them to make a "bread of affliction", and also use their milk to make cheese, matzah brie(always wondered why not matzah mozzarella or cheddar..).  There must be other ways to enjoy a perfectly shechted matzah, besides the traditional "Sinai oyster" soup..

So - what DO they do with the rest of the matzah?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 4):

I once went to a matzah slaughterhouse and I saw where the rest of the matzah goes. First, the thick outer casing of the matzah is removed to make "matzos" tefillin, and the thinner parts of the casing are used for klaf. Ever wondered why klaf has a spotty, rough, appearance? That's matzah's characteristic blister and burnt-patch pattern. The outer part of matzah is usually sold to non-kosher establishments as it's not profitable to remove the dark, nerve-like, border that always forms along the edges of the matzah. Round *shmura* matzah is so much more expensive in part because the border is painstakingly removed.

Answer (score 2):

As the original matza was baked in the desert, it is only appropriate that the rest of the matza goes back to the desert so that travelers will be able to find it, easily.

Jeremiah 31:1 even attests to this:

> כה אמר ה' מצה כן במדבר
>
> Thus said G-d: There, indeed, is matzah in the desert

Comment: Thanks, Dan..getting there! I like the first answer, because it's perfectly ridiculous, but it's unsourced...yours is sourced but doesn't have that element of pure impossibility and humor - which is what I look for in PT questions and answers..but that's just me.."who is this Herb guy?"etc.